# How to add fade transitions in between state changes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this component that every time I change the value of the state I want it to fade between the different colors rather than change straight away how do I do this?

````
const Header = (props) => {
    const [headerColor, setHeaderColor] = useState('#c8e9e6');

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
            console.log(window.scrollY);
            if (window.scrollY < 700) {
                setHeaderColor('#c8e9e6');
               
            } else if (window.scrollY >= 700 && window.scrollY < 1500) {
       
                setHeaderColor('#ffae5a');
            } else if (window.scrollY >= 500) {
                setHeaderColor('#b48fff');
            }
        });
    });
    return (
        <div className={classes.HeaderContainer} style={{
            backgroundColor: headerColor,
        }```);
}
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably just add a css class the transition by using the property `transition` & -`webkit-transition`

For example set the colour to orange after 2 seconds:

```
.transaition{
    background-color: #ffae5a;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: background-color 2s;
}
```